# Discord.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined in a user defined

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

in the code you see below what it do is connect to a mongodb database, and get user ID stored, and works fine, the problem is sending to that user ID a message, here is the code:

```
const { MongoClient, ReadPreference } = require('mongodb');

    const MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/';

    (async() => {
        const mongoClient = await MongoClient.connect(MONGO_URL, {
            appname: 'test',
            readPreference: ReadPreference.PRIMARY,
            useNewUrlParser: true,
        });
        const db = await mongoClient.db('test');
        const changeStream = db.collection('tools').watch([], { 'fullDocument': 'updateLookup' });

        changeStream.on('change', (event) => {
            tool.findOne({
                code: datos,
            }, async(err, s) => {
                console.log(datos)
                const userID2 = s.userID;
                if (!s) {
                    console.log("pin no encontrado")
                }
                if (userID2 != undefined) {
                    try {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            console.log("userID2 = " + userID2)
                            console.log("Event" = event);
                            console.log("event.updateDescription.updatedFields =" + event.updateDescription.updatedFields)
                            const user = client.users.cache.get(userID2)
                            console.log("const user = " + user)
                            user.send("Resultados del scan: " + "\nEstá el usuario cheat? " + event.updateDescription.updatedFields.cheats + "\nCheats que tiene el usuario: " + event.updateDescription.updatedFields.namecheats)
                        }), 5000
                    } catch (e) { console.log("[ERROR]", e) }
                } else { return }
            });
        })
    })();
})
```

And here is the output in console:

```
651312
userID2 = 794601739960844348
{
  _id: {
    _data: '82600D5062000000012B022C0100296E5A1004D5046A26D5AE482380F594D10FDC475546645F69640064600CA9A0FE28E8160C78C34E0004'
  },
  operationType: 'update',
  clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1611485282 },
  fullDocument: {
    _id: 600ca9a0fe28e8160c78c34e,
    serverID: '802595009617723412',
    userID: '794601739960844348',
    __v: 0,
    cheats: 'true',
    code: '651312'
  },
  ns: { db: 'test', coll: 'tools' },
  documentKey: { _id: 600ca9a0fe28e8160c78c34e },
  updateDescription: { updatedFields: { cheats: 'true' }, removedFields: [] }
}
{ cheats: 'true' }
const user = undefined
/home/jonh/bot-tool/src/index.js:101
                            user.send("Resultados del scan: " + "\nEstá el usuario cheat? " + event.updateDescription.updatedFields.cheats + "\nCheats que tiene el usuario: " + event.updateDescription.updatedFields.namecheats)
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/jonh/bot-tool/src/index.js:101:34)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:556:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:7)
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/jonh/bot-tool
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node .

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-01-24T10_48_02_631Z-debug.log
```

As you can see, in the output, it logs userID2 = 794601739960844348 and the user ID is good, but for some reason it didnt send the message to that user.
I already tried with fetch() and it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code instead:

```js
                        setTimeout(async function() {
                            console.log("userID2 = " + userID2)
                            console.log("Event" = event);
                            console.log("event.updateDescription.updatedFields =" + event.updateDescription.updatedFields)
                            const user = await client.users.fetch(userID2)
                            console.log("const user = " + user)
                            user.send("Resultados del scan: " + "\nEstá el usuario cheat? " + event.updateDescription.updatedFields.cheats + "\nCheats que tiene el usuario: " + event.updateDescription.updatedFields.namecheats)
                        }, 5000)
```

(fetch the user and fix the set timeout)